# how to update record with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I just want to update records with linq. This is the query that I want:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var query = db.Surrenders.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(int.Parse(query_id.Value.ToString()))).Select(s => s).ToList();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.IsRead = false;
            db.SubmitChanges();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Well I found some useful things that state "LINQ is just for querying" not for upadting.
How can I make changes with `db.SubmitChanges();`?

Comment: LINQ is a querying language, but can be used with other technologies, like LINQ-To-Entities, which allows you to work with databases.

Comment: It is not LINQ query which is updating records in database, it is LINQ TO SQL's `SubmitChanges` which does the job. You are still **only** querying data through LINQ

Comment: ya i'm working with it just see db.

Comment: `but this is not works.` ... Do you get an error? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: You are only setting the first item.IsRead to false. Maybe thats what you want, but you should probably move the SaveChanges outside the loop and if you just want to change the first item, use FirstOrDefault instead of Where. And then check for null.

Comment: i don't have db.SaveChanges means replaces with db.SubmitChanges error not occurs at run time.

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt- ok now it's working i just make one mistake i have to set like item.IsRead = true; and yes just have to put db.SubmitChanges() out of loop. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are issuing the `break` keyword, which lets you quit your loop, so only one iteration is made. Additionally, you can move your `SubmitChanges()` out of the loop, so it is only called once, and not once per iteration.

Remove it so your snippet looks like this:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var query = db.Surrenders.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(int.Parse(query_id.Value.ToString()))).Select(s => s).ToList();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
         if (item != null)
         {
             item.IsRead = false;
         }
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```